# Cloudwatch - how to use percentile?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I thought percentile was something that was supported in Cloudwatch, but if i try to add this to my query:

```
| stats precentile(someValue, 90)
```

For getting the p90 of `someValue`, it complains that `precentile` is not a recognized option..
Does Cloudwatch not support precentile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for `pct`:

```
pct(fieldName: LogFieldValue, percent: number)
```

> A percentile indicates the relative standing of a value in a dataset. For example, `pct(@duration, 95)` returns the `@duration` value at which `95` percent of the values of `@duration` are lower than this value, and `5` percent are higher than this value.

Source: [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html)

Comment: Thanks! And if i set `| limit 5`, can i get the p90 of only those 5?

Comment: `| limit` applies to how many lines are returned. It does not apply before that statistics being calculated as far as I've seen.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, CloudWatch Logs Insights supports percentile. The syntax is:

```
pct(fieldName: LogFieldValue, percent: number)
```

For example:

```
stats pct(@duration, 90)
```

[image]

---

Reference:
[CloudWatch Logs Insights query syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html)